Understanding Ignorability and Confounding Variables
I am reading Data Analysis Using Regression and Hierarchical Models and am confused by the concept of ignorability. The description in the book seems to say different things.

Said another way,
we would not necessarily expect any two (school) classes to have had the same probability
of receiving the supplemental version of the treatment. However, we expect any
two (school) classes at the same levels of the confounding covariates (that is, pre-treatment
variables; in our example, average pre-test score) to have had the same probability
of receiving the supplemental version of the treatment.


A third way to think about
the ignorability assumption is that it requires that we control for all confounding
covariates, the pre-treatment variables that are associated with both the treatment and the outcome.

To me the first statement seems to say that within any given level of confounding variables (eg for students with low/med/high pre-test scores) the distribution of treatment vs control should be about equal. Aka, if students with low pre-test scores have the same probability of receiving the treatment as not, then the number of students with low pre-test scores who receive the treatment should be about equal to the number who don't. However, this usually (almost by definition?) won't be true of a confounding variable. In most cases, a confounding variable is confounding because more units receive the treatment at some levels of the confounder than others. So then how could ignorability ever be satisfied if there are any confounding variables even if they are controlled for?
In the book they also write:

This says that the distribution of the potential outcomes, (y0, y1), is the same across levels of the treatment variable, T , once we condition on confounding covariates X.

This seems to agree nicely with this explanation here. Given this definition, I'm wondering, is it ever actually possible to determine if ignorability is satisfied? What are some ways of determining if it is or is not?

The definition of (conditional-on-T) ignorability depends on partially unobserved outcomes, so it is an untestable assumption that must be justified with your knowledge of the setting. You only ever see half of the Ys for each student: the one corresponding to their treatment status. People will also disagree if you have have all the confounders that influence both treatment and outcomes in your data or have the right functional form.
For instance, if the assignment is made by some school district bureaucrat who never met the students, uses a strict rule that you know, and you have all the data she used, conditional ignorability might be plausible. You could go out and find kids from classes where there was no treatment who would have been assigned to treatment given their pre-treatment characteristics. This is why sometimes the definition of ignorability is unconfounded assignment plus an overlap in probability of treatment between the two groups.
If the assignment is made by a teacher or principal who knows the students, the assumption is harder to swallow. Perhaps he has a private signal of which students would really benefit from the program and which would be just fine without it. Maybe there are parents who nag the teacher to assign the student to treatment, and that concern also manifests in better outcomes through increased parental involvement.
I should also say that it’s not the number of students in each group, it’s their potential outcomes that matter here. It’s perfectly fine for the groups to be of unequal size within blocks defined by X.
